# Will Ansible prevent the execution of 'rm -rf /' in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, ansible, rm

This is based upon this [hoax question](https://serverfault.com/questions/769357/recovering-from-a-rm-rf) here.  The problem described is having a bash script which contains something to the effect of:

```
rm -rf {pattern1}/{pattern2}
```

...which if both patterns include one or more empty elements will expand to at least one instance of `rm -rf /`, assuming that the original command was transcribed correctly and the OP was doing [brace expansion rather than parameter expansion](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-expand.html).

In the OP's [explanation of the hoax](http://www.snopes.com/man-deletes-company-code/), he states:

> The command [...] is harmless but it seems
>   that almost no one has noticed.
>
> The Ansible tool prevents these errors, [...] but [...] no one seemed to
>   know that, otherwise they would know that what I have described could
>   not happen.

So assuming you have a shell script that emits an `rm -rf /` command through either brace expansion or parameter expansion, is it true that using [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) will prevent that command from being executed, and if so, how does it do this?

Is executing `rm -rf /` with root privileges really "harmless" so long as you're using Ansible to do it?

Comment: I debated what to do with this question, but ultimately I decided to upvote and answer it, so as to move towards finally putting this whole sorry ridiculous mess in the past where it belongs.

Comment: I think the answer really lies in the `rm` source, which I analyzed below.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I have virtual machines, let's blow a bunch of them up! For science.

```
[root@diaf ~]# ansible --version
ansible 2.0.1.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

First attempt:

```
[root@diaf ~]# cat killme.yml 
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Die in a fire
      command: "rm -rf {x}/{y}"
[root@diaf ~]# ansible-playbook -l localhost -vvv killme.yml
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
1 plays in killme.yml

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [Die in a fire] ***********************************************************
task path: /root/killme.yml:5
ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
localhost EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 22 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461128819.56-86533871334374 `" && echo "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461128819.56-86533871334374 `" )'
localhost PUT /tmp/tmprogfhZ TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461128819.56-86533871334374/command
localhost EXEC /bin/sh -c 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461128819.56-86533871334374/command; rm -rf "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461128819.56-86533871334374/" > /dev/null 2>&1'
changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["rm", "-rf", "{x}/{y}"], "delta": "0:00:00.001844", "end": "2016-04-20 05:06:59.601868", "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "rm -rf {x}/{y}", "_uses_shell": false, "chdir": null, "creates": null, "executable": null, "removes": null, "warn": true}, "module_name": "command"}, "rc": 0, "start": "2016-04-20 05:06:59.600024", "stderr": "", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": ["Consider using file module with state=absent rather than running rm"]}
 [WARNING]: Consider using file module with state=absent rather than running rm


PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

OK, so `command` just passes the literals along, and nothing happens.

How about our favorite safety bypass, [`raw`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/raw_module.html)?

```
[root@diaf ~]# cat killme.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Die in a fire
      raw: "rm -rf {x}/{y}"
[root@diaf ~]# ansible-playbook -l localhost -vvv killme.yml
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
1 plays in killme.yml

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [Die in a fire] ***********************************************************
task path: /root/killme.yml:5
ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
localhost EXEC rm -rf {x}/{y}
ok: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "rm -rf {x}/{y}"}, "module_name": "raw"}, "rc": 0, "stderr": "", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

No go again! How hard can it possibly be to delete all your files?

Oh, but what if they were undefined variables or something?

```
[root@diaf ~]# cat killme.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Die in a fire
      command: "rm -rf {{x}}/{{y}}"
[root@diaf ~]# ansible-playbook -l localhost -vvv killme.yml
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
1 plays in killme.yml

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [Die in a fire] ***********************************************************
task path: /root/killme.yml:5
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'x' is undefined"}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
        to retry, use: --limit @killme.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Well, that didn't work.

But what if the variables are defined, but empty?

```
[root@diaf ~]# cat killme.yml 
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Die in a fire
      command: "rm -rf {{x}}/{{y}}"
  vars:
    x: ""
    y: ""
[root@diaf ~]# ansible-playbook -l localhost -vvv killme.yml
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
1 plays in killme.yml

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [Die in a fire] ***********************************************************
task path: /root/killme.yml:5
ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
localhost EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 22 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461129132.63-211170666238105 `" && echo "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461129132.63-211170666238105 `" )'
localhost PUT /tmp/tmp78m3WM TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461129132.63-211170666238105/command
localhost EXEC /bin/sh -c 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461129132.63-211170666238105/command; rm -rf "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461129132.63-211170666238105/" > /dev/null 2>&1'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["rm", "-rf", "/"], "delta": "0:00:00.001740", "end": "2016-04-20 05:12:12.668616", "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "rm -rf /", "_uses_shell": false, "chdir": null, "creates": null, "executable": null, "removes": null, "warn": true}, "module_name": "command"}, "rc": 1, "start": "2016-04-20 05:12:12.666876", "stderr": "rm: it is dangerous to operate recursively on ‘/’\nrm: use --no-preserve-root to override this failsafe", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": ["Consider using file module with state=absent rather than running rm"]}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
        to retry, use: --limit @killme.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Finally, some progress! But it still complains that I didn't use `--no-preserve-root`.

Of course, it also warns me that I should try using [the `file` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html) and `state=absent`. Let's see if that works.

```
[root@diaf ~]# cat killme.yml 
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Die in a fire
      file: path="{{x}}/{{y}}" state=absent
  vars:
    x: ""
    y: ""
[root@diaf ~]# ansible-playbook -l localhost -vvv killme.yml    
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
1 plays in killme.yml

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [Die in a fire] ***********************************************************
task path: /root/killme.yml:5
ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
localhost EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 22 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461129394.62-191828952911388 `" && echo "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461129394.62-191828952911388 `" )'
localhost PUT /tmp/tmpUqLzyd TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461129394.62-191828952911388/file
localhost EXEC /bin/sh -c 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461129394.62-191828952911388/file; rm -rf "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1461129394.62-191828952911388/" > /dev/null 2>&1'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"backup": null, "content": null, "delimiter": null, "diff_peek": null, "directory_mode": null, "follow": false, "force": false, "group": null, "mode": null, "original_basename": null, "owner": null, "path": "/", "recurse": false, "regexp": null, "remote_src": null, "selevel": null, "serole": null, "setype": null, "seuser": null, "src": null, "state": "absent", "validate": null}, "module_name": "file"}, "msg": "rmtree failed: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/boot'"}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
        to retry, use: --limit @killme.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

[Good news, everyone!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6ODMDtG6-I) It started *trying* to delete all my files! But unfortunately it ran into an error. I'll leave fixing that and getting the playbook to destroy everything using the `file` module as an exercise to the reader.

---

**DO NOT run any playbooks you see beyond this point!** You'll see why in a moment.

Finally, for the *coup de grâce*...

```
[root@diaf ~]# cat killme.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Die in a fire
      raw: "rm -rf {{x}}/{{y}}"
  vars:
    x: ""
    y: "*"
[root@diaf ~]# ansible-playbook -l localhost -vvv killme.yml
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
1 plays in killme.yml

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [Die in a fire] ***********************************************************
task path: /root/killme.yml:5
ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
localhost EXEC rm -rf /*
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/process/result.py", line 102, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/process/result.py", line 76, in _read_worker_result
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 117, in get
ImportError: No module named task_result
```

This VM is [an ex-parrot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vuW6tQ0218)!

Interestingly, the above failed to do anything with `command` instead of `raw`. It just printed the same warning about using `file` with `state=absent`.

I'm going to say that it appears that if you aren't using `raw` that there is some protection from `rm` gone amok. **You should not rely on this, though.** I took a quick look through Ansible's code, and while I found the warning, I did not find anything that would actually suppress running the `rm` command.

Comment: +1 for science. I'd +1 more for the host name, but it would be fraud ;p/

Comment: Looks like you might have a filesystem mounted at `/boot`.

Comment: @84104 Funny, that. By sheer coincidence, `boot` is the first directory entry in `/`. So no files were lost.

Comment: So `/1-usr-local-is-for-people-who-know-what-is-what` might have been lost had it existed?

Comment: @84104 The low level `readdir()` reads directory entries in on-disk order, which for a newly created filesystem is going to be the order the inodes were created. Since this is a freshly installed VM, it created the `/boot` mountpoint right after creating the filesystem, and thus it was naturally first. As directory entries get deleted, new ones take those places, and a directory is wildly out of order. Try `ls -U` to see the actual on-disk order. Practically, `/boot` is unlikely to ever be deleted, so it will always retain its first position in the directory.

Comment: Hooray for science!  Though seems like `rm` should get at least some of the credit for preventing disaster with its `--no-preserve-root` check?

Comment: @aroth Exactly! But, for science, try `rm -rf {{x}}/{{y}}` when `y` is set to `"*"`. The `--no-preserve-root` check is useful for what it is, but it will not get you out of every possible situation; it's easy enough to bypass. Which is why that question wasn't caught out as a hoax immediately: Taking into account the bad English and the apparent syntax errors, _it is plausible_.

Comment: Besides [`raw`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/raw_module.html), a bad [`cron`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/cron_module.html) might be another way to wreck a system.

Comment: Now to get all the news outlets reporting the hoax to report on this post instead, people might learn something!

Comment: Cool man that is a great experience.

Answer (score 3):

## Will Ansible prevent the execution of `rm -rf /` in a shell script?

I did inspect the coreutils [rm source](http://lingrok.org/xref/coreutils/src/rm.c#324), which has the following:

```
  if (x.recursive && preserve_root)
    {
      static struct dev_ino dev_ino_buf;
      x.root_dev_ino = get_root_dev_ino (&dev_ino_buf);
      if (x.root_dev_ino == NULL)
        error (EXIT_FAILURE, errno, _("failed to get attributes of %s"),
               quoteaf ("/"));
    }
```

The only way to wipe *from the root* is to get past this code block. From [this source](http://lingrok.org/xref/coreutils/gl/lib/root-dev-ino.c):

```
struct dev_ino *
get_root_dev_ino (struct dev_ino *root_d_i)
{
  struct stat statbuf;
  if (lstat ("/", &statbuf))
    return NULL;
  root_d_i->st_ino = statbuf.st_ino;
  root_d_i->st_dev = statbuf.st_dev;
  return root_d_i;
}
```

I interpret this to mean that the the function `get_root_dev_ino` returns null on `/`, and thus rm fails.

The only way to bypass the first code block (with recursion) is to have `--no-preserve-root` and it does no use an environment variable to override, so it would have to be passed explicitly to rm.

I believe this proves that unless Ansible explicitly passes `--no-preserve-root` to `rm`, it will not do this.

## Conclusion

I do not believe that Ansible explicitly prevents `rm -rf /` because `rm` itself prevents it.